# Android Studio autoTextSizeType with app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, textview

According to [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html) it is possible to use the new `autoSizeTextType` functionality in apps that target API versions lower than v26 by using the `app:` namespace.

My root layout element is a `LinearLayout` and it has the `app` namespace tag.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    etc
```

My TextView is defined as follows:

```
        <Android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/each_pays_amount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:text="@string/decimal_zeroes"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="140sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

In my app.iml I have the following:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.tbuonomo.andrui:viewpagerdotsindicator:1.0.1'
}
```

Whenever the layout loads, however, my app crashes with the following error:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.nooriginalthought.yabs, PID: 8640
              android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: 
              Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class Android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class Android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "Android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView" on path: D.......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I now have this working and it seems there were a couple of simple issues that needed resolving...

- first of all, originally I was not including `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'` in my `app.iml` I was only including the `support:support` library
- I have also now included the `app` namespace declaration in the `AppCompatTextView` element as well as the root element of my layout. (Not 100% sure this is necessary, but adds clarity to markup anyway)
- next, when including the `AppCompatTextView` in my layout I had the root `android.` starting with a capital 'A' - that was causing the crash on inflation.
- finally I made sure that my `AppCompatTextView` elements were set to `width="match_parent"` so that they had somewhere to expand into.

Putting all of this together has got things working.

The only change to the code in the question as it looks now is to change the upper case 'A' to a lower case, giving:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:id="@+id/each_pays_amount"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:text="@string/decimal_zeroes"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="140sp"
    ... />
```

Comment: Guess it should work even without the app namespace in the AppCompatTextView declaration. Also i didn't have to use the match_parent for the width. Updated my answer with my usage.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this answer:
[Autosizing of TextView doesn't work (Android O)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44118002/autosizing-of-textview-doesnt-work-android-o)
You have to put that line outside of the view, if you find your answer looking at the link please share what was the problem, hope this helped!

Edit: I found this answer too: [TextView autoSizeTextType is not detecting in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410809/textview-autosizetexttype-is-not-detecting-in-xml)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use AppCompatTextView (instead of textview) and supportLibrary 26.0.1.
`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-beta2'` or higher

Refer As suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46349091/6616489

I have used it like

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
android:id="@+id/text_view_label"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
tools:text="Type"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"/>
```

Comment: I've tried this, actually using v27.0.2 and my app crashes every time this layout is viewed with the following error: `FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.nooriginalthought.yabs, PID: 8640                                         android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class Android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView (I'll update question with latest info)

Comment: I am using the AppCompatTextview as mentioned and it works fine.
would this help ?
https://faheart.com/789474/how-to-debug-appcompat-textview-inflateexception

Comment: The linked discussion is about a missing attribute causing the layout inflate to fail. My failure is because the `Android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView` class is not found in 'the path'...

Comment: The crash was caused by the capital 'A' in `Android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView` - it should be `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView`.

Comment: Yeah, feel a bit stupid missing it - but would also have expected lint to have picked it up.

Answer (score -1):

As per the page you mentioned in the question, To define the default setting in XML, use the android namespace and set the autoSizeTextType attribute to none or uniform.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    **android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"** />
```

instead of app:autoSizeTextType="uniform", please try android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" and let us know if that solves the issue?? 
......

Comment: Hi, this is not an definitive answer and should be put in comments.  Since you do not have the reputation for comments yet, you will have to wait.

Comment: As per the first line of the question, I need to support API versions lower than 26. Using `autoSizeTextType` in the `android` namespace is only possible for API 26 and above. Using the android namespace /does/ work on API26+ targets, but that doesn't help me i this case.