# Android xml: TextView auto sizing not working

Tags: android, xml

consider the following code snippet of a layout.

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:text="Auto Sizing Not Working"/>
```

My only guess now is that an app theme attribute is causing autoSizeTextType to be null and void; as it is not the first time. windowNoTitle has caused my app to crash mysteriously already.

I am kindly asking for a well accustomed android developer to aid me with a working solution.

Comment: Maybe this one can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410809/textview-autosizetexttype-is-not-detecting-in-xml

Comment: I don't think themes override attributes to null unless it's specificly documented to do so. Did you take a look at here ? There's a whole section for resizing. Maybe you missed minSize, maxSize & granularity https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview

Comment: I want to quickly thank you all for the content.

Comment: Alright a study of the links shows me that I must have Android 8 OS to use regular TextView; otherwise I must use a support library. My big problem is I am using ApkBuilder, a mobile app, which doesnt support android support libraries. I guess I have to do this programatically.

Answer (score 0):

With having an updated version of `AppCompat` library (e. g. `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0`) in your project, you can have the auto-size feature simply like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="This is a sample text here"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
```

Note that as far as I know `AppCompatTextView` and `TextView` have problems with `wrap_content` so you should provide a fixed `width` and `height` for them to work properly.

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you. However I now know I am doomed until I get a labtop. Or if an android app is created that supports android support library. I am using ApkBuilder and it doesnt support it. Also JStudio doesnt support them either. Or maybe I must tweak its gradle file.